# navigator.connection is undefined in Phonegap Developer App (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-developer-app

I have a problem with the Phonegap Developer app. When I try to access some plugins like `network-information` or `contacts`, I get a `is undefined` error. For example this code:

```
alert(navigator.connection);
```

shows a alert box saying `undefined`.

The documentation says that this app supports core plugins by default, so I don't know what is wrong here.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are likely not waiting for the [`deviceready`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) event

Comment: Yes, I am! I wrote that line in the `deviceready` event handler and it didn't work.

Comment: I have working examples. You should refine you question by adding the `index.html`. Make sure to include the code that has the `deviceready` and the `navigator.connection`. The code is the more important part.